# Building dlib fails in docker container

Tags: python, docker, machine-learning, build, dlib

**The Question**

I have a docker image that builds fine on my local machine (Ubuntu 20.04) but fails on a shared [Linode](https://www.linode.com/products/shared/) when compiling [dlib](https://pypi.org/project/dlib/). And I have absolutely no clue why this is happening.

Anybody knows or has any idea what to do? I assume it has something to do with the underlying hardware but what do I know...

**Further Background**

- Docker and Docker Compose version are the same on both systems
- all requirements for building dlib are met (proven by my successfull local build)
- I have an image based on `nvidia/cuda:11.0.3-cudnn8-runtime-ubuntu20.04`
- As I think the missing GPU on the Linode has something to do with it I tried to compile dlib without GPU support with several methods. None worked
- In the end the image exposes a Django API that does a bunch of Machine Learning stuff (using e.g. spacy or face-recognition).

**The error message**

```
Installing collected packages: dlib
      Running setup.py install for dlib: started
      Running setup.py install for dlib: still running...
      Running setup.py install for dlib: still running...
      Running setup.py install for dlib: still running...
      Running setup.py install for dlib: still running...
      Running setup.py install for dlib: still running...
      Running setup.py install for dlib: still running...
      Running setup.py install for dlib: still running...
      Running setup.py install for dlib: still running...
      Running setup.py install for dlib: still running...
      Running setup.py install for dlib: still running...
      Running setup.py install for dlib: finished with status 'error'
      ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
       command: /home/picwise/.pyenv/versions/3.7.11/bin/python3.7 -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-req-build-owm_69xz/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-req-build-owm_69xz/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-4bup0pba/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/picwise/.pyenv/versions/3.7.11/include/python3.7m/dlib
           cwd: /tmp/pip-req-build-owm_69xz/
      Complete output (267 lines):
      running install
      running build
      running build_py
      package init file 'tools/python/dlib/__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
      running build_ext
      Building extension for Python 3.7.11 (default, Oct  4 2021, 20:45:45)
      Invoking CMake setup: 'cmake /tmp/pip-req-build-owm_69xz/tools/python -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=/tmp/pip-req-build-owm_69xz/build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7 -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/home/picwise/.pyenv/versions/3.7.11/bin/python3.7 -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release'
      -- The C compiler identification is GNU 9.3.0
      -- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 9.3.0
      -- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
      -- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
      -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
      -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
      -- Detecting C compile features
      -- Detecting C compile features - done
      -- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
      -- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
      -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
      -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
      -- Detecting CXX compile features
      -- Detecting CXX compile features - done
      -- Found PythonInterp: /home/picwise/.pyenv/versions/3.7.11/bin/python3.7 (found version "3.7.11")
      -- Found PythonLibs: /home/picwise/.pyenv/versions/3.7.11/lib/libpython3.7m.a
      -- Performing Test HAS_CPP14_FLAG
      -- Performing Test HAS_CPP14_FLAG - Success
      -- pybind11 v2.2.4
      -- Using CMake version: 3.16.3
      -- Compiling dlib version: 19.22.1
      -- SSE4 instructions can be executed by the host processor.
      -- AVX instructions can be executed by the host processor.
      -- Enabling AVX instructions
      -- Looking for pthread.h
      -- Looking for pthread.h - found
      -- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD
      -- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD - Failed
      -- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
      -- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
      -- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
      -- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - found
      -- Found Threads: TRUE
      -- Could NOT find X11 (missing: X11_X11_INCLUDE_PATH X11_X11_LIB)
       *****************************************************************************
       *** DLIB GUI SUPPORT DISABLED BECAUSE X11 DEVELOPMENT LIBRARIES NOT FOUND ***
       *** Make sure libx11-dev is installed if you want GUI support.            ***
       *** On Ubuntu run: sudo apt-get install libx11-dev                        ***
       *****************************************************************************
      -- Searching for BLAS and LAPACK
      -- Searching for BLAS and LAPACK
      -- Found PkgConfig: /usr/bin/pkg-config (found version "0.29.1")
      -- Checking for module 'cblas'
      --   No package 'cblas' found
      -- Checking for module 'lapack'
      --   No package 'lapack' found
      -- Looking for cblas_ddot
      -- Looking for cblas_ddot - not found
      -- Looking for sys/types.h
      -- Looking for sys/types.h - found
      -- Looking for stdint.h
      -- Looking for stdint.h - found
      -- Looking for stddef.h
      -- Looking for stddef.h - found
      -- Check size of void*
      -- Check size of void* - done
       *****************************************************************************
       *** No BLAS library found so using dlib's built in BLAS.  However, if you ***
       *** install an optimized BLAS such as OpenBLAS or the Intel MKL your code ***
       *** will run faster.  On Ubuntu you can install OpenBLAS by executing:    ***
       ***    sudo apt-get install libopenblas-dev liblapack-dev                 ***
       *** Or you can easily install OpenBLAS from source by downloading the     ***
       *** source tar file from http://www.openblas.net, extracting it, and      ***
       *** running:                                                              ***
       ***    make; sudo make install                                            ***
       *****************************************************************************
      CUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR not found or specified
      -- Could NOT find CUDA (missing: CUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR CUDA_NVCC_EXECUTABLE CUDA_INCLUDE_DIRS CUDA_CUDART_LIBRARY) (Required is at least version "7.5")
      -- Found CUDA, but CMake was unable to find the cuBLAS libraries that should be part of every basic CUDA install. Your CUDA install is somehow broken or incomplete. Since cuBLAS is required for dlib to use CUDA we won't use CUDA.
      -- DID NOT FIND CUDA
      -- Disabling CUDA support for dlib.  DLIB WILL NOT USE CUDA
      -- C++11 activated.
      -- Configuring done
      -- Generating done
      -- Build files have been written to: /tmp/pip-req-build-owm_69xz/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7
      Invoking CMake build: 'cmake --build . --config Release -- -j1'
      Scanning dependencies of target dlib
      [  1%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/base64/base64_kernel_1.cpp.o
      [  2%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/bigint/bigint_kernel_1.cpp.o
      [  2%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/bigint/bigint_kernel_2.cpp.o
      [  3%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/bit_stream/bit_stream_kernel_1.cpp.o
      [  4%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/entropy_decoder/entropy_decoder_kernel_1.cpp.o
      [  4%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/entropy_decoder/entropy_decoder_kernel_2.cpp.o
      [  5%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/entropy_encoder/entropy_encoder_kernel_1.cpp.o
      [  5%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/entropy_encoder/entropy_encoder_kernel_2.cpp.o
      [  6%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/md5/md5_kernel_1.cpp.o
      [  7%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/tokenizer/tokenizer_kernel_1.cpp.o
      [  7%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/unicode/unicode.cpp.o
      [  8%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/test_for_odr_violations.cpp.o
      [  9%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/sockets/sockets_kernel_1.cpp.o
      [  9%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/bsp/bsp.cpp.o
      [ 10%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/dir_nav/dir_nav_kernel_1.cpp.o
      [ 11%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/dir_nav/dir_nav_kernel_2.cpp.o
      [ 11%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/dir_nav/dir_nav_extensions.cpp.o
      [ 12%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/gui_widgets/fonts.cpp.o
      [ 13%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/linker/linker_kernel_1.cpp.o
      [ 13%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/logger/extra_logger_headers.cpp.o
      [ 14%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/logger/logger_kernel_1.cpp.o
      [ 14%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/logger/logger_config_file.cpp.o
      [ 15%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/misc_api/misc_api_kernel_1.cpp.o
      [ 16%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/misc_api/misc_api_kernel_2.cpp.o
      [ 16%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/sockets/sockets_extensions.cpp.o
      [ 17%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/sockets/sockets_kernel_2.cpp.o
      [ 18%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/sockstreambuf/sockstreambuf.cpp.o
      [ 18%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/sockstreambuf/sockstreambuf_unbuffered.cpp.o
      [ 19%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/server/server_kernel.cpp.o
      [ 20%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/server/server_iostream.cpp.o
      [ 20%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/server/server_http.cpp.o
      [ 21%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/threads/multithreaded_object_extension.cpp.o
      [ 22%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/threads/threaded_object_extension.cpp.o
      [ 22%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/threads/threads_kernel_1.cpp.o
      [ 23%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/threads/threads_kernel_2.cpp.o
      [ 24%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/threads/threads_kernel_shared.cpp.o
      [ 24%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/threads/thread_pool_extension.cpp.o
      [ 25%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/threads/async.cpp.o
      [ 25%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/timer/timer.cpp.o
      [ 26%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/stack_trace.cpp.o
      [ 27%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/cuda/cpu_dlib.cpp.o
      [ 27%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/cuda/tensor_tools.cpp.o
      [ 28%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/data_io/image_dataset_metadata.cpp.o
      [ 29%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/data_io/mnist.cpp.o
      [ 29%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/data_io/cifar.cpp.o
      [ 30%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/global_optimization/global_function_search.cpp.o
      [ 31%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/filtering/kalman_filter.cpp.o
      In file included from /tmp/pip-req-build-owm_69xz/dlib/filtering/../matrix.h:11,
                       from /tmp/pip-req-build-owm_69xz/dlib/filtering/kalman_filter.h:7,
                       from /tmp/pip-req-build-owm_69xz/dlib/filtering/kalman_filter.cpp:6:
      /tmp/pip-req-build-owm_69xz/dlib/filtering/../matrix/matrix_la.h: In function â€˜long int dlib::svd4(dlib::svd_u_mode, bool, const dlib::matrix_exp<EXP>&, dlib::matrix<typename EXP::type, uM, uN, MM1, L1>&, dlib::matrix<typename EXP::type, qN, qX, MM2, L1>&, dlib::matrix<typename EXP::type, vM, vN, MM3, L1>&) [with EXP = dlib::matrix_op<dlib::op_trans<dlib::matrix_op<dlib::op_trans<dlib::matrix<double, 1, 2, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char>, dlib::row_major_layout> > > > >; long int qN = 1; long int qX = 1; long int uM = 1; long int uN = 1; long int vM = 2; long int vN = 1; MM1 = dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char>; MM2 = dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char>; MM3 = dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char>; L1 = dlib::row_major_layout]â€™:
      /tmp/pip-req-build-owm_69xz/dlib/filtering/../matrix/matrix_la.h:225:32: warning: iteration 1 invokes undefined behavior [-Waggressive-loop-optimizations]
        225 |             y = abs(q(i)) + abs(e(i));
            |                             ~~~^~~~~~
      /tmp/pip-req-build-owm_69xz/dlib/filtering/../matrix/matrix_la.h:163:20: note: within this loop
        163 |         for (i=0; i<n; i++)
            |                   ~^~
      [ 31%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/svm/auto.cpp.o
      [ 32%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libpng/arm/arm_init.c.o
      [ 33%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libpng/arm/filter_neon_intrinsics.c.o
      [ 33%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libpng/png.c.o
      [ 34%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libpng/pngerror.c.o
      [ 34%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libpng/pngget.c.o
      [ 35%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libpng/pngmem.c.o
      [ 36%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libpng/pngpread.c.o
      [ 36%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libpng/pngread.c.o
      [ 37%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libpng/pngrio.c.o
      [ 38%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libpng/pngrtran.c.o
      [ 38%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libpng/pngrutil.c.o
      [ 39%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libpng/pngset.c.o
      [ 40%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libpng/pngtrans.c.o
      [ 40%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libpng/pngwio.c.o
      [ 41%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libpng/pngwrite.c.o
      [ 42%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libpng/pngwtran.c.o
      [ 42%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libpng/pngwutil.c.o
      [ 43%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/zlib/adler32.c.o
      [ 44%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/zlib/compress.c.o
      [ 44%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/zlib/crc32.c.o
      [ 45%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/zlib/deflate.c.o
      [ 45%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/zlib/gzclose.c.o
      [ 46%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/zlib/gzlib.c.o
      [ 47%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/zlib/gzread.c.o
      [ 47%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/zlib/gzwrite.c.o
      [ 48%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/zlib/infback.c.o
      [ 49%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/zlib/inffast.c.o
      [ 49%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/zlib/inflate.c.o
      [ 50%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/zlib/inftrees.c.o
      [ 51%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/zlib/trees.c.o
      [ 51%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/zlib/uncompr.c.o
      [ 52%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/zlib/zutil.c.o
      [ 53%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/image_loader/png_loader.cpp.o
      [ 53%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/image_saver/save_png.cpp.o
      [ 54%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jaricom.c.o
      [ 54%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jcapimin.c.o
      [ 55%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jcapistd.c.o
      [ 56%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jcarith.c.o
      [ 56%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jccoefct.c.o
      [ 57%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jccolor.c.o
      [ 58%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jcdctmgr.c.o
      [ 58%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jchuff.c.o
      [ 59%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jcinit.c.o
      [ 60%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jcmainct.c.o
      [ 60%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jcmarker.c.o
      [ 61%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jcmaster.c.o
      [ 62%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jcomapi.c.o
      [ 62%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jcparam.c.o
      [ 63%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jcprepct.c.o
      [ 64%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jcsample.c.o
      [ 64%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jdapimin.c.o
      [ 65%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jdapistd.c.o
      [ 65%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jdarith.c.o
      [ 66%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jdatadst.c.o
      [ 67%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jdatasrc.c.o
      [ 67%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jdcoefct.c.o
      [ 68%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jdcolor.c.o
      [ 69%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jddctmgr.c.o
      [ 69%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jdhuff.c.o
      [ 70%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jdinput.c.o
      [ 71%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jdmainct.c.o
      [ 71%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jdmarker.c.o
      [ 72%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jdmaster.c.o
      [ 73%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jdmerge.c.o
      [ 73%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jdpostct.c.o
      [ 74%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jdsample.c.o
      [ 74%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jerror.c.o
      [ 75%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jfdctflt.c.o
      [ 76%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jfdctfst.c.o
      [ 76%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jfdctint.c.o
      [ 77%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jidctflt.c.o
      [ 78%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jidctfst.c.o
      [ 78%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jidctint.c.o
      [ 79%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jmemmgr.c.o
      [ 80%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jmemnobs.c.o
      [ 80%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jquant1.c.o
      [ 81%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jquant2.c.o
      [ 82%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jutils.c.o
      [ 82%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/image_loader/jpeg_loader.cpp.o
      [ 83%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/image_saver/save_jpeg.cpp.o
      [ 84%] Linking CXX static library libdlib.a
      [ 84%] Built target dlib
      Scanning dependencies of target _dlib_pybind11
      [ 84%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/_dlib_pybind11.dir/src/dlib.cpp.o
      [ 85%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/_dlib_pybind11.dir/src/matrix.cpp.o
      [ 85%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/_dlib_pybind11.dir/src/vector.cpp.o
      [ 86%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/_dlib_pybind11.dir/src/svm_c_trainer.cpp.o
      c++: fatal error: Killed signal terminated program cc1plus
      compilation terminated.
      make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/_dlib_pybind11.dir/build.make:102: CMakeFiles/_dlib_pybind11.dir/src/svm_c_trainer.cpp.o] Error 1
      make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:117: CMakeFiles/_dlib_pybind11.dir/all] Error 2
      make: *** [Makefile:84: all] Error 2
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
        File "/tmp/pip-req-build-owm_69xz/setup.py", line 261, in <module>
          'Topic :: Software Development',
        File "/home/picwise/.pyenv/versions/3.7.11/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 144, in setup
          return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
        File "/home/picwise/.pyenv/versions/3.7.11/lib/python3.7/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
          dist.run_commands()
        File "/home/picwise/.pyenv/versions/3.7.11/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
          self.run_command(cmd)
        File "/home/picwise/.pyenv/versions/3.7.11/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "/home/picwise/.pyenv/versions/3.7.11/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/install.py", line 61, in run
          return orig.install.run(self)
        File "/home/picwise/.pyenv/versions/3.7.11/lib/python3.7/distutils/command/install.py", line 545, in run
          self.run_command('build')
        File "/home/picwise/.pyenv/versions/3.7.11/lib/python3.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "/home/picwise/.pyenv/versions/3.7.11/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "/home/picwise/.pyenv/versions/3.7.11/lib/python3.7/distutils/command/build.py", line 135, in run
          self.run_command(cmd_name)
        File "/home/picwise/.pyenv/versions/3.7.11/lib/python3.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "/home/picwise/.pyenv/versions/3.7.11/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "/tmp/pip-req-build-owm_69xz/setup.py", line 134, in run
          self.build_extension(ext)
        File "/tmp/pip-req-build-owm_69xz/setup.py", line 174, in build_extension
          subprocess.check_call(cmake_build, cwd=build_folder)
        File "/home/picwise/.pyenv/versions/3.7.11/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 363, in check_call
          raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
      subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', '--build', '.', '--config', 'Release', '--', '-j1']' returned non-zero exit status 2.
      ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /home/picwise/.pyenv/versions/3.7.11/bin/python3.7 -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-req-build-owm_69xz/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-req-build-owm_69xz/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-4bup0pba/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/picwise/.pyenv/versions/3.7.11/include/python3.7m/dlib Check the logs for full command output.
  

  at /home.pyenv/versions/3.7.11/lib/python3.7/site-packages/poetry/utils/env.py:1075 in _run
      1071â”‚                 output = subprocess.check_output(
      1072â”‚                     cmd, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, **kwargs
      1073â”‚                 )
      1074â”‚         except CalledProcessError as e:
    â†’ 1075â”‚             raise EnvCommandError(e, input=input_)
      1076â”‚ 
      1077â”‚         return decode(output)
      1078â”‚ 
      1079â”‚     def execute(self, bin, *args, **kwargs):

The command '/bin/bash -o pipefail -c poetry install     $(test \"$PICWISE_DJANGO_ENVIRONMENT\" == production && echo \"--no-dev\")     --no-interaction     --no-ansi' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem by upgrading my Linode to a [dedicated CPU plan](https://www.linode.com/products/dedicated-cpu/). After doing so everything worked as expected.

**For me this problem is solved** but I am still curious why this did not work on the shared system... If anybody know, please enlighten me!